# is there any function to choose Random character from a given string in DART

Tags: dart

I am new to DART, and i would like to know is there any way to choose random characters from am given string in DART.

Any built-in functions available?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use the `Random` class from `dart:math` to make your own function:

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  print(getRandomLetter('Hello World'));
}

final _rnd = Random();
String getRandomLetter(String input) => input[_rnd.nextInt(input.length)];
```